# Regex match data independently of order and availability, output should be captured groups, in defined order

Tags: regex

I have system logs with optional request data inserted into them when certain request or action happens.

For example consider the following log entry:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss PID | INFO | endpoint=SomeEndpoint, transactionId=12345, userId=67890 | Some log message
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The part that I'm trying to parse with regex is, as underlined:

```
endpoint=SomeEndpoint, transactionId=12345, userId=67890
```

That additional data can be in any order, it might be missing some of it or be missing completely.

For example **all** of those are possible as log messages:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss PID | INFO | transactionId=12345, endpoint=SomeEndpoint, userId=67890 | Some log message
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss PID | INFO | userId=67890, endpoint=SomeEndpoint | Some log message
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss PID | INFO | transactionId=12345 | Some log message
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss PID | INFO |  | Some log message
```

I managed to match them in random order using a positive lookahead like this:

```
\|\s*(?=[^\|]*endpoint=(?<endpoint>\w+))(?=[^\|]*transactionId=(?<transactionId>[\w-]+))(?=[^\|]*userId=(?<userId>[\w-]+)).*\s*\|
```

But this requires me to have all of the keys `endpoint`, `transactionId`, `userId` present to have a match. Is there a way to match only the data available inside? If some are missing or all of them are missing I want the regex to pass. If the data is there I want it in the specific regex group.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: are they always appear in the third position split by `|`? In that case, you can write regex to match the third column only

Comment: They are to be parsed by fluent bit. Yes I can match the third column, but I need the data sorted into matching groups, not the whole string.

Comment: To be clear, you mean the order of the *keys* (`endpoint`, `transactionId`, `userId`) is independent. But not independent order of the characters, e.g. 'Iduser'. So, independent only at the word-level, not character level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *regex conditional with look around*, you can check the look around successful or not before matching text into group.

I changed your regex to accomplish your requirement.

```
[^|]+\|[^|]+\|\s*(?(?=[^\|]*endpoint=)(?=[^\|]*endpoint=(?<endpoint>\w+)))(?(?=[^\|]*transactionId=)(?=[^\|]*transactionId=(?<transactionId>[\w-]+)))(?(?=[^\|]*userId=)(?=[^\|]*userId=(?<userId>[\w-]+))).*\s*\|
```

Check this sample : https://regex101.com/r/xAhXvw/1

Comment: Didn't know that form. Can also be achieved with 'simple' look-aheads and optional non-capturing groups: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yolRUx/1).

Comment: Thank you @PJProudhon, it’s much simpler than my answer

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to make use of `\G` which will match at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string.

Then use named capturing groups which you can refer to to check which of the values are present.

```
(?:\G(?!^)|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|)\s*(?:transactionId=(?<transactionId>[\w-]+)|endpoint=(?<endpoint>\w+)|userId=(?<userId>[\w-]+)),?
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\G(?!^)` Assert end of the previous match if not at the start
  - `|` Or
  - `[^|]+\|[^|]+\|)\s*` From the start match 2 times not a `|` followed by a `|`
  - `(?:` Non capturiing group

    - `transactionId=(?<transactionId>[\w-]+)` Match transactionId in named capturing group
    - `|` Or
    - `endpoint=(?<endpoint>\w+)` Match endpoint in named capturing group
    - `|` Or
    - `userId=(?<userId>[\w-]+` Match userId in named capturing group
  - `)` Close group
- `),?` Close group and match an optional comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LkPKYx/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but I'm not sure I understand it completely. I will try to go deeper into that solution as well :)